# Invoke constructor based on passed parameter

Tags: scala, constructor

Constructing an object based on passed parameter. But the parameter is not String.
I found the solution how to do it with String
[Scala instantiate objects from String classname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384370/scala-instantiate-objects-from-string-classname)
but I believe that it can be done nicer.
Let's say the following classes:

```
sealed trait Figure
object Figure {
    final case class Circle(radius: Double) extends Figure
    final case class Square(a: Double) extends Figure
}
```

And let's define a function (which doesn't make sense) which take a parameter based on I can invoke the proper constructor:

```
val construct123: Figure => Either[String, Figure] = (figure: Figure) => Right(figure.apply(1.23))
```

I want to invoke

```
construct123(Circle)
//or
construct123(Square)
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: You want a typeclass or reflection, neither of which I would recommend to someone who is learning the language.

Comment: Your `figure` parameter is not a `Figure`, but rather a `Function1[Int, Figure]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest would be to modify the signature of `construct123` slightly

```
def construct123(figure: Double => Figure): Either[String, Figure] =
  Right(figure(1.23))

construct123(Circle.apply) // Right(Circle(1.23))
construct123(Square.apply) // Right(Square(1.23))
construct123(Circle(_)) // Right(Circle(1.23))
construct123(Square(_)) // Right(Square(1.23))
construct123(Circle) // Right(Circle(1.23))
construct123(Square) // Right(Square(1.23))
```

Or `construct123` can be written as a higher-order function

```
val construct123: (Double => Figure) => Either[String, Figure] =
  figure => Right(figure(1.23))
```

[Difference between method and function in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala)

---

`Circle` and `Square` in `construct123(Circle)` and `construct123(Square)` are not the case classes `Circle` and `Square` but their companion objects

[Class companion object vs. case class itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75286750/class-companion-object-vs-case-class-itself)

So actually you want to transform an object into an instance of its companion class. You can do this for example with a [macro](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html)

```
// libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def construct123[A](figure: A): Either[String, Figure] = macro construct123Impl[A]

def construct123Impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context)(figure: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  val companionClass = weakTypeOf[A].companion
  q"_root_.scala.Right.apply(new $companionClass(1.23))" // using constructor of the case class
}
```

or

```
def construct123Impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context)(figure: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  val A = symbolOf[A].asClass.module
  q"_root_.scala.Right.apply($A.apply(1.23))" // using apply method of the companion object
}
```

Testing (in a different subproject):

```
construct123(Circle) // Right(Circle(1.23))
construct123(Square) // Right(Square(1.23))

   // scalacOptions += "-Ymacro-debug-lite"
//scalac: scala.Right.apply(new Macros.Figure.Circle(1.23))
//scalac: scala.Right.apply(new Macros.Figure.Square(1.23))

//scalac: scala.Right.apply(Circle.apply(1.23))
//scalac: scala.Right.apply(Square.apply(1.23))
```

---

You can hide the work with macros in type classes (defined with whitebox [implicit macros](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/implicits.html)). The type class `ToCompanion` below is similar to `HasCompanion` in [Get companion object of class by given generic type Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172775/get-companion-object-of-class-by-given-generic-type-scala) ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74726266/5249621)). The type class `Generic` from [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) (used below to define `construct123`) is also macro-generated. Some intros to type classes (ordinary, not macro-generated): [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408861/what-are-type-classes-in-scala-useful-for) [2](https://kubuszok.com/2018/implicits-type-classes-and-extension-methods-part-1/) [3](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html) [4](https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html) [5](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/type-classes) [6](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/types-type-classes.html) [7](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/type-classes.html) [8](https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c19557030181c0dc36533f3de7d7abf4#typeclasses) [9](https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.html#sec:generic:type-classes)

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

// type class
trait ToCompanion[A] {
  type Out
}

object ToCompanion {
  type Aux[A, Out0] = ToCompanion[A] {type Out = Out0}
  // materializer
  def apply[A](implicit tcc: ToCompanion[A]): ToCompanion.Aux[A, tcc.Out] = tcc
  // def apply[A](implicit tcc: ToCompanion[A]): tcc.type = tcc

  // instance of the type class
  implicit def mkToCompanion[A, B]: ToCompanion.Aux[A, B] = macro mkToCompanionImpl[A]
  // implicit def mkToCompanion[A]: ToCompanion[A] = macro mkToCompanionImpl[A] // then implicitly[ToCompanion.Aux[Circle, Circle.type]] doesn't compile in spite of white-boxity

  def mkToCompanionImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val A = weakTypeOf[A]
    val companion = A.companion
    val ToCompanion = weakTypeOf[ToCompanion[A]]
    q"new $ToCompanion { type Out = $companion }"
  }
}
```

```
implicitly[ToCompanion.Aux[Circle, Circle.type]] // compiles
implicitly[ToCompanion.Aux[Circle.type, Circle]] // compiles

val tc = ToCompanion[Circle.type]
implicitly[tc.Out =:= Circle] // compiles
val tc1 = ToCompanion[Circle]
implicitly[tc1.Out =:= Circle.type] // compiles

// libraryDependencies += "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.10"
import shapeless.{::, Generic, HNil}

def construct123[A, B <: Figure](figure: A)(implicit
  toCompanion: ToCompanion.Aux[A, B],
  generic: Generic.Aux[B, Double :: HNil]
): Either[String, Figure] = Right(generic.from(1.23 :: HNil))

construct123(Circle) // Right(Circle(1.23))
construct123(Square) // Right(Square(1.23))
```

---

Since all the classes are now known at compile time it's better to use compile-time reflection (the above macros). But in principle [runtime reflection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html) can be used too

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => rm}
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def construct123[A: TypeTag](figure: A): Either[String, Figure] = {
  val classSymbol = symbolOf[A].companion.asClass
  //val classSymbol = typeOf[A].companion.typeSymbol.asClass
  val constructorSymbol = typeOf[A].companion.decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
  val res = rm.reflectClass(classSymbol).reflectConstructor(constructorSymbol)(1.23).asInstanceOf[Figure]
  Right(res)
}
```

or

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => rm}
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def construct123[A: TypeTag : ClassTag](figure: A): Either[String, Figure] = {
  val methodSymbol = typeOf[A].decl(TermName("apply")).asMethod
  val res = rm.reflect(figure).reflectMethod(methodSymbol).apply(1.23).asInstanceOf[Figure]
  Right(res)
}
```

---

Or you can use structural types aka duck typing (i.e. also runtime reflection under the hood)

```
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls

def construct123(figure: { def apply(x: Double): Figure }): Either[String, Figure] =
  Right(figure(1.23))
```